# Dynamically Adding Parameters to CountIfs in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to use countifs in VBA without knowing the amount of criteria/ranges. So in the example below, my script would see that there were 2 criterias, and apply 2 sets of criteria/ranges.

How do I do this in VBA, I can do everything apart from put it in the countifs formula. I tried putting it in a string/variant, ie: Application.Worksheetfunctions.Countifs(stringvariable) but it has not worked, I understand why it has not worked but I can't find a way to do this.

Thanks in Advance for your help.

[image: Demo Information]

Comment: Hard to tell where your code is in error without seeing the code. It should be doable if you construct the formula appropriately.  Another approach would be to use the Advanced Filter and then the SubTotal "CountA" function, all of which can be implemented in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create the formula as a string 
2) Use application.evaluate(var) to get the result